# Executing Selenium 2 jar with Jenkins as part of a PHPUnit test raises error

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I've build a small java application that uses selenium 2 to open a web page and return its result.

The application is called as a part of a PHPUnit test which is in turn run as part of an ANT build.

The problem is when the Jenkins builds the project and runs the test the following error shows

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect
>   to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms

When I run the build in the command line in the jenkis working directory it all works fine. I think that the problems is that the jenkins service doesn't have enought security permissions.

This is the first line of the console output of the jenkis build

> Started by user anonymous

The os is Ubuntu 9

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the jenkins user wasn't able to connect to a X sessions. The solution was really simple.

First we need to install a vnc server:

> sudo apt-get install tightvncserver

Then we need to switch to the jenkins user and start the vncserver for the first time in order to set its password:

> sudo su jenkins
>   vncserver

The password I'v set is **jenkins** and I've answered with **N** to the do you wan't to create a view only password.

Then I needed to install the Xvnc plugin on the jenkins plugin administration panel and to tick the "Run a vnc server during" builds checkbox.

Everything else worked just fine.